# Expresion Regular C# con números,caracteres y espacios

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, regex

He estado intentado construir una ***regex*** de 0  para unas validaciones de números de teléfono, al ser variadas las posibilidades se  me complico, solucione una parte pero no logro armar lo que sigue; debería admitir por ejemplo:

> **+5411 3118-2380 011 3044-8008 3225-2587 215547891**

Logré una primera parte con lo siguiente:

```
^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+\\)?$
```

pero sin lograr poder obtener que me acepte espacios ni guion.

Comment: ¿Quieres que sólo valide que es un número de teléfono o quieres que además capture los valores?

Comment: con que me valide esos tres tipos de teléfonos es mas que suficiente

Comment: ¿Algo así: `\+?(?:[\d-]+ ?)+`?

Comment: perfecto algo asi ! Muchisimas gracias !! Crack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esta expresión:

```
\+?(?:[\d-]+ ?)+
```

---

#### **Explicación**.

```
\+?                | símbolo de prefijo internacional opcional.
   (?:        )+   | grupo de no-captura repetido una o varias veces.
      [\d-]+       | uno o más guiones o números.
             ?     | seguido de uno o ningún espacio.
```